# How can i choose random number smaller than "1000" or "n" in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

How can i choose random number smaller than "1000" or "n"?

```
Do While ddd <> 1
    Static staticRandomGenerator As New System.Random

    max += 1
    dd = staticRandomGenerator.Next(If(min > max, max, min), If(n > max, min, max))
    ddd = ee * dd Mod z
Loop
```

How can i add this condition to this code? Any idea?

Comment: `dd = RNG.Next(min, 1000)` will pick a value between whatever the min is and less than 1000 every time.  Dont create the RNG in the loop though - guarantees they will all be the same

Comment: I have to put random number in loop, because i have another condition,
i need random number to put it in this _Math_ and **ddd** must be equal **1**
`ddd = ee * dd Mod z`

Comment: No.  `Static staticRandomGenerator As New System.Random` that line IN the loop almost guarantees that the same seed will be used.  Why is it static anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, that code is correct, but i need to add another condition.

Comment: The question/answer is in C# but the principle is the same. The Random variable initialization should be outside of the loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Comment: @Plutonix: his code doesn't in fact initialise the RNG inside the loop.  The initialisation on a _static_ variable is only executed the first time it is encountered.  I'm not saying it's a good way of writing it, but his code will initialise the RNG once and reuse the same one each time henceforth (even reusing the same one without re-initialisation if the function is called again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two** ways to generate a random number in VB.NET (that I am familiar with).

***Technique 1:***

```
randomNumber = CInt(Math.Floor((n - 0 + 1) * Rnd())) + 0
```

**n** = Upperbound value, otherwise known as the highest value randomNumber can be, which in your case you would have already defined as 1000.

**0** = Lowerbound value, otherwise known as the *lowest* value the randomNumber can be.

You can find more info about this technique [***here***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx).

***Technique 2:***

```
Dim rn As New Random
randomNumber = rn.Next(0, n)
```

Again, **n** = Upperbound value, otherwise known as the highest value randomNumber can be, which in your case you would have already defined as 1000.

And again, **0** = Lowerbound value, otherwise known as the lowest value randomNumber can be.

*I cannot find a link to an official post about this on the Microsoft MSDN site, but if anyone can find a good post about this technique, please comment, or message me.*

**I hope this helps!**